# Change a Non Static Variable to Static Variable

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, metaspace

I am reading about the GC and read that when an object becomes eligible for garbage collection, the GC has to run the `finalize` method on it. The `finalize` method is guaranteed to run only once, thus the GC marks the object as finalized and gives it a rest until the next cycle.

In the finalize method, you can technically “resurrect” an object, for example, by assigning it to a static field. The object would become alive again and not eligible for garbage collection, so the GC would not collect it during the next cycle.

The object, however, would be marked as finalized, so when it would become eligible again, the finalize method would not be called. In essence, you can turn this “resurrection” trick only once for the lifetime of the object.

I find this fascinating. However, if my variable is non-static, how to I change it to the static inside the `finalize` method?

Remember:

An object becomes eligible for Garbage collection or GC if it is not reachable from any live threads or by any static references. So the hack is to add the object to a static resource inside the `finalize` method and this will prevent the garbage collection for only one time. The `finalize` method is protected, so, can be overridden by subclasses, whether they are in the same package or not.

This is a dangerous practice and no need to use inside application code.

Comment: You can't change whether or not a variable is static at execution time. Note that it's not your *variable* that's being finalized though - it's an *object*. So you could store a reference to that object in an existing static variable, for example. It's very unclear what your'e trying to achieve, to be honest.

Comment: You wouldn't change the variable itself since that's only a reference (and barring some nasty reflection tricks can't change it from non-static to static anyways) but assuming you'd have a static collection somehwere you could add the `this` reference to that collection. Note however that those "fascinating" things are _very very very_ tricky and unsafe and unless you _really_ know what you're doing you shouldn't use that in any production environment.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was reading this article (Q11): https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-management-interview-questions  and this is a reliable website for Java and Spring related articles.

Comment: @Arefe even the most reliable source is unreliable if you misunderstand it

Comment: @Thomas This makes sense, do you have time to write an answer?

Comment: Just a remark to “the GC has to run the `finalize` method on it”, for 99% of the all objects, the `finalize()` method will never be invoked. And when it is invoked, it’s not the garbage collector which invokes it, but dedicated finalizer threads (though this behavior is implementation specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a variable definition at runtime isn't easy and in some cases next to impossible. There might be some nasty reflection tricks that might involve inline compiling, classloading etc. but you shouldn't do that. Changing a variable from static to non-static or vice versa would also involve moving the data around in storage and deal with potential collisions - so don't do that.

Anyways variables are just references and to resurrect an object you'd just need to create a new reference from a live thread. That could be done with some collection that's referenced by a static variable and which the `this` reference is added to.

Example (for illustration purposes only, *do not use it unless you really know what you are doing and have a good reason to*):

```
class NastyResurrector {
  public static Collection<Object> RESURRECTED_OBJECTS = ...;// use whatever collection implementation you like
}
```

Then in `finalize()` you'd call `NastyResurrector.RESURRECTED_OBJECTS.add(this)` and there you have your reference.

However, I'll quote from the [source of your question](https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-management-interview-questions) (question Q11):

> Beware that this ugly hack should be used only if you really know what you’re doing

That's the most important takeaway in my opinion.

Comment: “*unless you really know what you are doing and have a good reason to*”. The former (“know what you are doing”) precludes the latter (“have a good reason”).

Comment: @Holger yes I first didn't have that "have a good reason" part but I figured I should add it to prevent a "if you have a hammer everything looks like a nail" kind of thinking :)